# Parse XML and apply syntax color

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse a simple XML Doc and create simple syntax coloring...

```
<parent>
   <child>Value</child>
   <child>
      <grandchild>Value2</grandchild>
   </child>
</parent>
```

So all the < and > are blue
The node names are red
and the value is black.

I was wondering if anyone had a good regex do this? Right now I am using a forloop and going character by character.... don't really think that is the best way so looking for ideas.

My XML will be  simple, won't ever have attributes, just a simple pattern like the above example. I would like to convert it to html.

Ideas?

Comment: What display mechanism will show the syntax coloring? Are you converting to HTML?

Comment: Yes HTML, sorry.... just added that to the question.

Comment: No regexp. If you want an XSLT solution, please say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You do not mention how you are rendering the output. But</strike> As a starting point, rather than parse the document character by character, you could use an [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) to read the XML nodes and then just emit the appropriate HTML output when you hit each node.

For example when you reach an element node, you can write out the '<' with a CSS style that renders in blue,  node.Name in red and '>' in blue, all other node type you write out in black. So the parsing is handled by the XmlTextReader and you are simply responsible for the presentation.

Comment: How do I maintain indentation?

Comment: The reader can return white space nodes which you can then write the appropriate html to present the whitespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype.aspx